# Find Probability that when a fair coin is flipped indefinitely a run of five heads occurs before run of two tails

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Find Probability that when a fair coin is flipped indefinitely a run of five heads occurs before run of two tails.

Here i assumed exactly $5$ consecutive heads appear before we get exactly $2$ consecutive tails.

For example the possibilities are

$1.$ $HHHHHTT $

$2.$ $THTHHHHHTT$

and so on

Now i assumed the string $HHHHH=X$ and $TT=Y$

we need probability that $X$ comes before $Y$

Can i have any clue?

Comment: Do you know about Markov chains?

Comment: no i dont know markov chain, all i know is what is random variable

Answer (score 1):

Let $H_5$ be the event we first encounter a run of five consecutive heads, and the complement $T_2$ be the event that we first encounter a run of two consecutive tails.

We flip a coin, the first.  Either we obtain a head or a tail.  Let $H$ be the event that the latest coin tossed was a head, and $T$ be that the latest coin tossed was a tail.

$$\mathsf P(H_5) = \tfrac 12\mathsf P(H_5\mid H)+ \tfrac 12\mathsf P(H_5\mid T)$$

- Case 1: We have a head and next either we obtain 4 more consecituve heads (then have $H_5$), or we obtain a tail before that (then are at case 2).
  $$\mathsf P(H_5\mid H) = \tfrac 1{16}+\tfrac {15}{16}\mathsf P(H_5\mid T)$$
- Case 2: We have a tail and next either we obtain another tail (then have $T_2$), or obtain a head (then are at case 1).
  $$\mathsf P(H_5\mid T) = 0+ \tfrac 12\mathsf P(H_5\mid H)$$

Solve the simultaneous equations.$${z=\tfrac 12(x+y)\\ x=\tfrac 1{16}+\tfrac {15}{16} y\\ y=\tfrac 12 x}$$

Comment: I believe would be instructive for the asker of the question to take your reasoning and generalize it to the case where $\Pr[H] = p$ for some $p \in (0,1)$.